# How function len replace text in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace

How the code `len(marker)` in function `replaced = line[:pos] + replacement + line[pos+len(marker):]` has removed the value of the string `marker` in the output as its is used to find the length of the string.

help me to understand.

```
#Example 1
marker = "AFK"
replacement = "away from keyboard"
line = "I will now go to sleep and be AFK until lunch time tomorrow."

pos = line.find(marker)
replaced = line[:pos] + replacement + line[len(marker)+pos:]

print replaced
```

output

```
I will now go to sleep and be away from keyboard until lunch time tomorrow.
```

Comment: `pos` will give you the index of `marker` string's start. `len(marker) + pos` will move to the whitespace right after `AFK` in order to avoid concatenating the word `AFK` in the new string.

Comment: Not answering because @vasilis does but I was just wondering why don't you use `string.replace()` ?

Comment: Thanks! for your explanation everyone, I have just started learning python so it was in the tutorial, but I was not able to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to find the index of "AFK" in the text `line`. This is done with

```
pos = line.find(marker)
```

We see that the answer is `30`. So we will take the text in `line` from the start to index 30. This is `I will now go to sleep and be`. Then we will append the text `away from keyboard`, then we will append the rest of the text in `line`.

So we will take the `len(marker)` which is `3`, so we will then add that to the value we got for `pos`. This turns out to be `33`. We will then go from index `33` all the way to the end of that sentence by `line[len(marker)+pos:]`.

All together we get

```
replaced = line[:pos] + replacement + line[len(marker)+pos:]
```

> I will now go to sleep and be away from keyboard until lunch time
>   tomorrow.